# Generate images on asp.net server using fabricjs

Tags: asp.net, html, canvas, fabricjs, node-canvas

I've been using FabricJS for some time now, have a panel which creates a template using FabricJS, saving this template in json format on server side. At run time I want to generate image files of saved template that is content of json file will be changing for example, have kept a placeholder to change text dynamically, but want to save this in image on server.

Is there anything similar to "node-canvas" for Microsoft asp.net MVC ?

Any pointers would definitely be of great help.

Thanks
~Jack

Comment: You have to do that client-side, because fabric.js needs the Canvas element to work with.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for your suggestion, yes that's the only option what I am looking down the line. Issue here,is I'll be creating 100's of images thru saved template that will take considerable amount of time. For now I think I should move on with this approach.